# NodeJS - OAuth server, using both API and Access key-token/secret

Tags: node.js, security, oauth

I'm trying to build an OAuth 1 server with NodeJS. I'm using oauthorize by Jared Hanson, but I can't figure out how to use both set of credentials. In the examples provided by Jared, I can find the flow in which the user is redirected to a page and authorizes the accesss to the application, but in my case I don't have user interaction. I've an external service which needs to consume some services on my NodeJS server. So, as I understand, the external services needs an API Key and Secret to identify itself in my NodeJS services, and after that, it needs Access Token/Secret (client) keys to perform operations in someone behalf on my NodeJS server.

All the examples I've seen, redirect the requester to a web page to authorize the access, but as I said before, in my case, there's no user interaction, so I'm stuck in how to proceed.

Can anyone please put me in the right track? My concept is wrong or is ok? If it's wrong, what path should I follow instead? If it's right, how do I implement it?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What you have mentioned is 3-legged OAuth which involves 3 parties(user,client,Oauthserver). In Oauth before a user can grant permission to a client it must authenticate itself first.

As you mentioned you don't want a web based authentication for user. Here is what you can do.
Oauthorize uses passport library to handle authentication.

passport allows authentication using different methods and they are called strategies,the example by Jared uses local-strategy. here is the snippet of code take

```
exports.login = passport.authenticate('local', { successReturnToOrRedirect: '/', failureRedirect: '/login' });
```

Please pay attention to the keyword local. Now instead of this you can use  Basic or Digest strategy. read about it here [passport basic strategy](http://passportjs.org/guide/basic-digest/)

I feel you are confused between 2 legged and 3 legged authentication. Please read more about it and feel free to ask more question.

Comment: Thank you @1234varun, I will take a look at that and continue doing tests. I'll report shortly with my tests results. Thanks!